# Is there an API to upload images to SE's imgur installation?

Tags: support, feature-request, api, images

Is there an API for uploading images to the StackExchange-specific imgur installation?  I could use the main imgur site, but they don't keep the images indefinitely.

Use case:  It would be advantageous to be able to rasterize graphics and upload them from Mathematica directly, especially since Mathematica-related questions/answers often need illustrations, and graphics are so tightly integrated into the Mathematica dev environment.

Comment: You basically need one thing: Stack Exchange's API key for imgur - which they are probably not likely to divulge.

Comment: @George Is that a "no" answer, i.e. this is currently not possible?

Comment: I can't give an official answer as to whether this is planned or whatever - but as far as I can tell, no - this is not possible.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison, how does your red circle script (I forget the name of it) keep the images then? I thought you had used SE's imgur account?

Comment: @Jonathan: No, it had its own hosting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not available.

Something like it *may* be available in the V3.0 timeframe, but I can't commit to that at this time.

Comment: Would SE be alright with us doing, in effect, what the [other answer](http://stackapps.com/a/5000/26088) says to do? So sending a POST request to /upload/image?

Answer (score 10):

While this is not available I don't think SE can do much to prevent it. I don't have any easily readable code to give you code example, but the theory is following:

#### The upload request:

To upload images to Stack Exchange, you must send following POST request to `https://__HOST__/upload/image`:

```
fkey: we'll talk about this token later
source: web/computer

filename: the file data binary file, source must be computer
upload-url: url of target image, source must be web
```

#### The `fkey` token:

If you're logged in, the `fkey` token is in a hidden input field:

```
<input id="fkey" type="hidden" value="..." name="fkey">
```

If not, it can be parsed out of `StackExchange.init()` call:

```
preg_match("~StackExchange\.init\(([^;]+)\);~s", $html, $m)
$data = json_decode($m[1], true);
```

That's it. You don't even have to be logged on.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that this might change/break any time without notice.  [This was the original motivation](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5/12) for the question.  In fact it already broke once, then it was fixed.

Comment: Yes, it's a hack, not an official way to do it.

Comment: Just do `fkey().fkey` in chat or `StackExchange.options.user.fkey` on main sites

Comment: fkey.value gives the result

Comment: Also, is this `fkey` site specific?

Answer (score 0):

Please note: this does not work anymore since [Mobile app infrastructure has been decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/295232).

---

There is sort of a workaround which my [Broken Image Repairer script](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f) is already using. You do need an access token that is tied to one of the official Stack Exchange mobile apps, e.g. by using a proxy like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) to inspect traffic between the app on your smartphone and the API server.

You'll need to make a POST call to https://mobile.stackexchange.com/1/image/upload and supply the following parameters (as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`):

- `access_token`
- `key` (the iOS app uses `kJ1geZUa*oJVMN229qwESg((`, the Android app `r0aEx)wmOcRhhPMdffXeUQ((`)
- `image_mime_type`: `image/png`, `image/jpeg` or `image/gif` (other image types are not supported)
- `image_name`: just a random string, doesn't really matter
- `filter`: `vqc7J` (I have no idea which fields these correspond to, since this call is not documented)
- `image_data`: the image data, encoded as Base64

If the upload succeeds, you'll get the URL back (the response is in the usual API style, a root object with an `items` array; there'll be a single item with a `url` property).