# How to get an API key without registering an application?

Tags: support, quota

How can I get an API key for doing 10K daily requests, without registering an application? Because I only use a script for my Social Network analysis project.

Answer (score 1):

[Registration](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) is quite simple; for 10k requests per day, you don't need fancy authentication stuff or a Stack Apps post for the app; just having a key suffices. See the documentation about [Throttles](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

The only option I know of (but would recommend against) is to use a key of an existing app published by someone else. You can use the ones from the official mobile apps; I've listed them [here](https://stackapps.com/a/8657/34061).